# Mustache section in Couchdb issues

Tags: couchdb, mustache

I am a couchdb newbie running CouchDB 1.0.1.

I have a very basic issue.  I cannot get Mustache Sections to render in a list. 
Here is my list with the data hard coded from an example.

```
function(head, req) {
    start({
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        }
    });
var mustache = require("lib/mustache");
var view = {name: "Joe's shopping card",items: ["bananas", "apples"]};
var template = "{{name}}: <ul> {{#items}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/items}} </ul>";
return mustache.to_html(template,view);
```

Outputs:

```
Joe's shopping card: <ul> <li></li><li></li></ul>
```

Please help!!!

Thank you,
/ Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Oh barf, I just figured it out and it is a little rediculous.  Here it is for anyone else who wants to save some time.  Add this to your template "{{%IMPLICIT-ITERATOR}}".

So:

```
var template = "{{name}}: <ul> {{#items}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/items}} </ul>";
```

Becomes:

```
var template = "{{%IMPLICIT-ITERATOR}}{{name}}: <ul> {{#items}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/items}} </ul>";
```